# DateDiff By Day of Week Count Does Not Match Actual Count from Paper Calendar

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query that groups by day of the week basis:

```
SELECT DATENAME(DW,rct.rpt_date) [Day of The Week]
      ,DATEDIFF(day,CAST(@date_from as DATE),CAST(@date_to AS DATE) [Number]
      ,COUNT(DISTINCT rct.rpt_date) as [Occurrence / Active]
FROM receipt_summary rct
WHERE rct.rpt_date between CAST(@date_from as DATE) and CAST(@date_to AS DATE)
AND rct.bus_id = 10
GROUP BY DATENAME(DW,rct.rpt_date)
ORDER BY CASE DATENAME(DW,rct.rpt_date)
WHEN 'SUNDAY' THEN 1
WHEN 'MONDAY' THEN 2
WHEN 'TUESDAY' THEN 3
WHEN 'WEDNESDAY' THEN 4
WHEN 'THURSDAY' THEN 5
WHEN 'FRIDAY' THEN 6
WHEN 'SATURDAY' THEN 7 END
```

When I used DATEDIFF(wk,@dateFrom,@dateTo) as one the columns, the count in Number column is same across the seven days. It doesn't match the number I aimed to get when count comparing with using a paper calendar.

For example, between 1 December 2019 and 12 March 2020, I would expect to see 15 times of Sundays to Thursdays, while Fridays and Saturdays should show 14 times. The Inactive column is naturally a subtraction of Number - Occurrences. Per the problem above, Sunday - Thursday shows 14.

This screenshot is what I am hoping to achieve:

[image]

Can anyone help on this? Where exactly did I miss out on?

Note: For grouping by Day of the Month, I am aware that it is similar in structure except for replacing DATENAME(DW,date) with `DATENAME(D,rct.rpt_date) + CASE WHEN DAY IN (1,21,31) Then ...`etc, but how different will it be the handling in the DATEDIFF portion?

**UPDATE**
The updated screenshot shows the current and expected results:

[image: Current and expected result]

This is a calendar from December 2019 to March 2020. Drawn in boxes are number of Sundays, Mondays and so forth from (date from) to 12 March 2020 
(date to).

[image: Calendar from Dec 2019 to March 2020]

Comment: probably receipt date does not have all the dates for that range

Comment: I am not sure how to fix your query, but you can simplify your ORDER BY clause with the [DATEPART()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function. `ORDER BY DATEPART(DW,rct.rpt_date)`.

Comment: You state that "the count in Number column is same across the seven days". That would make sense because your Number column is defined as a difference between two variables, **@date_from** and **@date_to**, which have static values for all rows of the query results and thus the same value. I am not sure what you want there as you haven't really stated your objective. Can you tell us what you are trying to find?

Comment: DATEDIFF(wk) doesn't count blocks of seven days, it counts Sundays. As per [DATEDIFF (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql): DATEDIFF always uses Sunday as the first day of the week to ensure the function operates in a deterministic way.

Comment: @Isaac to clarify, I have added two more screenshots to illustrate my objective. The NUMBER column should reflect the number of Sundays / Mondays matching the calendar screenshot.

Comment: What are you values for the variables of @date_from and @date_to?

Comment: There are a number of issues your query that prevent any real progress in helping. I understand you may be trying to simplify it for our understanding and/or to leave out proprietary details. First, your columns names in your query do not match your results. Not a big deal, it just makes it harder to follow.  Second, your query cannot run as is because your calculation for **Number** is missing an ending parenthesis. And finally, if your calculation for Number had that right number of parentheses it would yield **102** which is the difference in days between your start and end dates.